Chinese New Year Question Challenge - Now On!
For this week, ending midnight on the 22nd of January, we are having a question asking challenge.
Everyone is encouraged to ask questions related to the passing of Chinese New Year 春节.
The person who asks the most upvoted questions will win some nice prize (still to be determined).
The idea is to provide the site with some quality questions and to have some friendly competition.
You are also welcome to ask (and answer) questions that you already know the answer to if they provide valuable information.
I look forward to seeing your great questions.
新年快乐！

When you are talking about "midnight", which time zone are you using? Or is there a default time zone on SE?

@fefe, if I recall correctly the timezone on SE is UTC - you'll notice that daily reputation changes at that time each day.

Update: The Challenge week has ended.

Great idea! Who doesn't love prizes? I've gone ahead and added my first CNY question, so fingers crossed.
And may I congratulate you on the awesome ideas you keep on coming up with for this site :-)

I was wondering, why don't we make your post CW and add here all the questions asked for this event for future reference? :)

I posted it on my own... :)

@Alenanno, great idea - good work :-)

You can edit it too of course, I might miss something :D


Premise: The questions are listed in order of posting. I thought about other orders but I also thought that this was the most "neutral". If you think other orders might be better, post a comment. 
If you post a new question that is not on this list, add it at the bottom of the list (please, use another question as a template, so it remains consistent). The first number you'll see represents the current1 votes.
1: This list is not automatically updated and the data might be mismatching.


3 — What and where is the connection between 压岁钱 and the character 岁 that appears in it?
posted by Alenanno
1 — Better translation for 春节联欢晚会 than New Year's Gala
posted by xiaohouzi79
0 — Use of 龙 in the idiom 车水马龙
posted by xiaohouzi79
2 — Is the character 年 (or its etymology) related to the mythical beast in Chinese mythology?
posted by Alenanno
5 — How to express a date in Chinese (lunar) calendar?
posted by Huang
1 — Is there a Chinese equivalent song of 'auld lang syne'?
posted by Ciaocibai
3 — Is there a traditional Chinese New Year greeting?
posted by Ciaocibai
3 — What is the exact meaning and etymology of 拜年？
posted by Ciaocibai
1 — Is the cantonese expression 五福臨門 present in Mandarin too?
posted by Alenanno
3 — How do Chinese native speakers actually refer to this event?
posted by Alenanno
1 — How should one answer this question about 年?
posted by Lagoona
1 — Can 窝 be used for grouping any zodiac animal?
posted by xiaohouzi79
Note: If you posted other questions, add them, there wasn't a tag system so I'm not sure which ones were posted for this challenge.

Is this the complete list? I want to get back to the SE team so they can select the winner. Thanks!

@xiaohouzi79 Nope, there are some "missings"... These are posted in order of time, so yours is the last one I compiled... :)
